# Java template class doesn't compile

Tags: java

I've the class LList that represents a particular collection of elements of type T. The class has a static method "empty()" and the method "ins"

```
public static <T> LList0<T> empty() {    
        LList0<T> emptyLList0 = new LList0<T>();
        emptyLList0.init = true;
        emptyLList0.list = null;
        emptyLList0.rest = null;
        emptyLList0.name = "empty";
        return emptyLList0;
    }

public LList0<T> ins(T o) { 
        LList0<T> c = new LList0<T>();          
        c.list = new Vector<T>();
        c.list.add(o);
        c.rest = this;
        c.init = true;       
        return c;
    }
```

I don't understand why

```
LList0<?> s4 = LList0.empty().ins(1).ins(2).ins(3);
```

works but

```
LList0<Integer> s4 = LList0.empty().ins(1).ins(2).ins(3);
```

does not work

Why in the first case the compiler will know to add the integers in the second case it gives the error?

```
type mismatch: cannot convert from LList<Object> to LList<Integer>
```

Comment: It would help if you supplied a simplified complete class `LList0<T>`. I certainly confused my own answer by constructing your class in the wrong way.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'Java template class'. Do you mean 'Java Generic class'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, because `LList0.empty()` without type hint will return `LList0<Object>`.

In first case `LList0<?> s4 = LList0.empty().ins(1);` `LList0<Object>` is casted to `LList0<?>`, which works just fine.

In second case `LList0<Integer> s4 = LList0.empty().ins(1);` you try to cast `LList0<Object>` to `LList0<Integer>` that doesn't compile for obvious reasons.

What you need to fix your situation is to add type hint to your call of `LList0.empty` method.

```
     LList0<Integer> s5 = LList0.<Integer>empty().ins(1);
```

This compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2):

#### problem 1

```
public static <T> LList0<T> empty()
```

even if you have `T` in the static  method, also in your `LList0` class, the both `T`s are different. The generic `T` in your static method **hides** (not use) the `T` in your class. That is, the returned `LList0` object has generic type `X`. You gave them same `T`, it is really confusing. That's why your first line worked, but 2nd line didn't. Keep in mind that if you have declared generic type `A` for a class and `B` for its static method. The `A` and `B` have nothing to do with each other, even if you name both as `T`!

#### problem 2

even if you fixed the generic type problem, your methods won't work as you expect. because each time you call `inc()`, the method generate a new `LList0` object, if you call `...inc(1).inc(2).inc(3)`, the returned `LList0` has only one element: `3`

Comment: Without a definition supplied for the rest of the class, isn't problem 1 merely an assumption on your part?

Comment: @Duncan  first sentence in OP's question tells that he had `<T>` in class. I think his problem was, he was confused by two different `<T>`s

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. I think you're spot on then.